# Shopify - App must set security headers to protect against clickjacking

Tags: reactjs, security, shopify, hadoop-yarn, shopify-app

I'm new to Shopify and I'm trying to help a friend with their website. I'm getting the following errors at the moment.

```
1. App must set security headers to protect against clickjacking.
Your app does not request installation on the shop immediately after clicking "add app". Apps must ask a shop for access when being installed on a shop for the first time, as well as when they are being reinstalled after having been removed. During install or reinstall we expected OAuth to be initiated at https://cambridgetestshop.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/request_grant but was redirected to https://app-staging.hashgifted.com/. Learn more about authentication in our developer documentation
2. App must verify the authenticity of the request from Shopify.
Your app does not request installation on the shop immediately after clicking "add app". Apps must ask a shop for access when being installed on a shop for the first time, as well as when they are being reinstalled after having been removed. During install or reinstall we expected OAuth to be initiated at https://cambridgetestshop.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/request_grant but was redirected to https://app-staging.hashgifted.com/. Learn more about authentication in our developer documentation
```

We're using React built in Yarn. I'm not sure about next steps, thanks!

Comment: you got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you're not following the documentation in regarding of authentication and app installation process.

As you're using node I suggest you to take a look at this project https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-node

and in particular to the authentication middleware, this is one part

```
import { Shopify } from "@shopify/shopify-api";

import topLevelAuthRedirect from "../helpers/top-level-auth-redirect.js";

export default function applyAuthMiddleware(app) {
  app.get("/auth", async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.signedCookies[app.get("top-level-oauth-cookie")]) {
      return res.redirect(
        `/auth/toplevel?${new URLSearchParams(req.query).toString()}`
      );
    }

    const redirectUrl = await Shopify.Auth.beginAuth(
      req,
      res,
      req.query.shop,
      "/auth/callback",
      app.get("use-online-tokens")
    );

    res.redirect(redirectUrl);
  });

  app.get("/auth/toplevel", (req, res) => {
    res.cookie(app.get("top-level-oauth-cookie"), "1", {
      signed: true,
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "strict",
    });

    res.set("Content-Type", "text/html");

    res.send(
      topLevelAuthRedirect({
        apiKey: Shopify.Context.API_KEY,
        hostName: Shopify.Context.HOST_NAME,
        host: req.query.host,
        query: req.query,
      })
    );
  });

  app.get("/auth/callback", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const session = await Shopify.Auth.validateAuthCallback(
        req,
        res,
        req.query
      );

      const host = req.query.host;
      app.set(
        "active-shopify-shops",
        Object.assign(app.get("active-shopify-shops"), {
          [session.shop]: session.scope,
        })
      );

      const response = await Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.register({
        shop: session.shop,
        accessToken: session.accessToken,
        topic: "APP_UNINSTALLED",
        path: "/webhooks",
      });

      if (!response["APP_UNINSTALLED"].success) {
        console.log(
          `Failed to register APP_UNINSTALLED webhook: ${response.result}`
        );
      }

      // Redirect to app with shop parameter upon auth
      res.redirect(`/?shop=${session.shop}&host=${host}`);
    } catch (e) {
      switch (true) {
        case e instanceof Shopify.Errors.InvalidOAuthError:
          res.status(400);
          res.send(e.message);
          break;
        case e instanceof Shopify.Errors.CookieNotFound:
        case e instanceof Shopify.Errors.SessionNotFound:
          // This is likely because the OAuth session cookie expired before the merchant approved the request
          res.redirect(`/auth?shop=${req.query.shop}`);
          break;
        default:
          res.status(500);
          res.send(e.message);
          break;
      }
    }
  });
}
```